# APACHE 2.4.16 Installation on AIX 5.3.0.0

Tags: apache, aix

Earlier I was using apache 2.2.31.But due to some security Issue like removing of Etag header from http header.

For this purpose I need to have mod_headers.so is not availabe in 2.2.31. is there any way to remove Etag Header without upgrading to apache 2.4.16 on AIX 5.3.0.0 ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried with official documentation for installation? Ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the inode from ETAG headers with the "FileETAG" directive. It's available in 2.2 (so is mod_headers):

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#fileetag

```
FileETag MTime Size
```

Comment: In modules directory mod_headers.so is not there.Is there any way to remove etag apart from the above solution

Comment: i tried the above solution but it is not working.Is there any way to remove etag.

Comment: thanks for your solution but the solution what you had suggested it is workinf only for all.do file not for jpg,js,.png,.js .can we have any solution that will hide etag for all tye of file

Comment: What context did you put it in in httpd.conf? How are these files generated?  The FileETAg directive only controls ETAGS generated/calculated by the webserver.

Comment: FileETag MTime Size only this i had edited in httpd.conf.after that i had restarted apache.